# Why can't I mount shares by SMB since High Sierra

Tags: mac, file-sharing, smb, macos-highsierra

Since I updated to High Sierra (directly to 10.13.1) I can't connect my
iMacs and MacBook any more by AFP protocol, so I tried SMB.

open 'smb://user:password@S/Share' :: works, but shows Finder on the screen.

Another problem is that I can't choose the mount point's name.
I work from JAVA applications and thus should work from the command line:

mkdir /Users/user/Volumes/Share/

/sbin/mount -t smbfs //user:password@S/F /Users/user/Volumes/Share/

But this gives:

mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error

What did I do wrong or forgot about?
Thanks in advance.
;JOOP!

Comment: I think this question is still not properly answered. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256716/why-mac-smb-connect-fails-with-login-from-cli-but-works-from-finder-and-with-gue is similar and also does not provide enough info. I'd appreciate if some of the downvoters would explain why they think this is all clear.

Answer (score 4):

I was encountering the same error "mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error" when attempting to connect via command line using the commands:

```
mkdir /Volumes/test
mount_smbfs //user@server/test /Volumes/test
```

However, I was able to elimate the error by going, on the server Mac, to System Preferences - Sharing - File Sharing - Options. Then under Windows File Sharing, click to enable the less-secure password option for the account you wish to use for sharing (optionally, create a sharing-only user for this purpose), and enter that account's password. I was then able to mount the share using the above commands.

Answer (score 1):

We were getting the dreaded `mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host` as well and it turned out to be a # symbol (aka pound sign, hashtag, number sign) in the password of the user that was the culprit! The # symbol happened to be the last character of that user's password. When using a different password, no more error.

A colleague came across the workaround to escape or quote in case you have special characters in password. Turns out a number of special characters at the end of a password cause this problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026168/escape-special-characters-in-mount-command

Specifically, if you get `mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host` errors, it may because special characters are not escaped in your password (or other)

So, a password such as `password$#`

We tried to add single quotes:

```
mount_smbfs '//someusername:somepassword$#@serverurl/shared' /Volumes/shared
```

instead of this:

```
mount_smbfs //someusername:password$#@serverurl/shared /Volumes/shared
```

but that did NOT work!

The only thing we could get working was to url encode the password to escape the special characters (use whatever method works - https://www.urlencoder.io/ for example or we used python urllib.parse.quote_plus(...) )

```
mount_smbfs //someusername:password%24%23@serverurl/shared /Volumes/shared
```

Note on  linux flavors use `mount -t cifs` or `mount -t smbfs` instead of `mount_smbfs` which is for Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of solved:

in File Sharing I had to store the passwords of the users involved under "Options".

I don't like this.

Answer (score 0):

The following command can run in High Sierra (tested in 10.13.6).

`mount_smbfs -f 0755 -d 0755 smb://username:passwd@SAMBA_SERVER/PATH /your_local_pre_exist_folder/`

Note: the "-f" and "-d" is optional.

Answer (score -1):

Are you by chance trying to authenticate to a Domain? Or specifically NOT wanting to use a Domain when the computer which hosts the remote filesystem *is* part of a Domain?

In my situation, my Mac is not on the domain, but the computer hosting the remote filesystem is on a domain. In order to force the remote computer to authenticate against a local user instead of a domain user, I have to use the keyword 'local' in the domain component:

```
mount -t smbfs '//local;user:password@S/F' /Volumes/Share
```