# SMB fileshare mount in OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, mount, cron, smb

So, I have had a cron-job running (on an Mac) for the last several weeks, doing backups on an SMB server we have at work.  Recently (in the last couple of weeks) it has started giving me authentication errors, and asking me for a password, which always seems to fail.  Essentially, the point that fails is:

```
mount_smbfs //smb/server/location ./mountpoint
```

This worked for a while, and it started giving me the error found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1269386/why-cant-i-mount-shares-by-smb-since-high-sierra?newreg=7873f66501c243758a29d83e898b62cc).  I've tried several different ways to mount this, such as:

```
mount_smbfs //username@smb/server/location ./mountpoint
mount_smbfs //username:password@smb/server/location ./mountpoint
mount -t smbfs //smb/server/location ./mountpoint
```

and several variations of the above.  They all give me the same authentication error, and I have been unable to mount this drive from the command line.

I have tried what the OP in the linked thread said worked for him, but I have had no luck.

Does anyone know what's changed with OSX's `mount_smbfs` in the last month?  And, more importantly, does anyone have any suggestions on how to remedy this issue?  I've hit this thing seven ways from Sunday, and I cannot get it to work.

---

**Just for clarification:**

- I was running Sierra, and it worked fine -- but started failing there.  So I've upgraded to High Sierra, and the issue still persists.
- I *KNOW* that the username/password combination is good, since I am using it to connect to the server through Finder without any problems.
- I do not know the *exact* time it stopped working, as I was not directly monitoring the cron-job, which is why it was a cron-job... it was working, and I just let it do its thing.
- I cannot manually start the backup, since it must be done when nobody is working on the server, and Finder likes to unmount drives after it's been locked and/or sleeping for a certain period of time... and this drive is no exception.

Comment: Check the logs on the SMB server too.  I'm assuming it's a Linux SMB box, but if it's Windows, there are LOTS of settings that restrict SMB access, so much so that I gave up mounting my Windows laptops on my Mac after Windows 7 came out and it stopped working.  So, I hope it's a Linux server and the logs there will tell you something constructive.

Comment: I wish I could... I sadly don't have access to the server itself.  This is why I'm trying to do a local backup.

Our IT guys aren't worried about the condition of the server, and my department doesn't want to lose all of their work, so I do periodic backups.  Something has changed (either on the server side, or the OSX side), and I can no longer manually mount it.

I have asked our IT guys to help solve this issue, but they see my backups as unnecessary, and refuse to put any time into solving the issue.